# find indices of overlapping ranges in R

Tags: r, indexing

my frame looks like this

```
4 8
6 9
1 2
5 7
10 14
3 9
```

in which the first col ist the start and the other col the end of a measure. I now want to return the indices of those rows which partly overlap a specific row. Example would row 1. The indices would be 2,4,6 - as these partly overlap. I need to make this comparison very frequently so an efficient solution would be great

note that i am looking not only for partly overlap but also complete overlap (3 9) ..

Comment: the function should just find the indices of those rows which overlap partly with a given row (in the question 1). I imagine this can be done through a series of greater equal comparisons but that is not very elegant

Comment: is it possib le to incorporate the indices of the row takes as comparison (in this exampel it is he first row) but just imagine it would be row 3

Comment: Do you want row 1 to be present in the output too?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution using `foverlaps()` function from the `data.table` package.

Set column names and pick the row index:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("start", "end")
indx <- 1L
```

Convert your data to a `data.table` object, set the column names and separate the specific row from the rest of the data and key it (this is an essential step - check `?foverlaps` for more).

```
setnames(setDT(df), cols)
temp <- setkeyv(df[indx], cols)
```

Run the `foverlaps` function. You can choose which type of overlap you want in the `type` parameter

```
foverlaps(df[-indx], temp, which=TRUE, 
          type="any", nomatch=0L)$xid + 1 
## [1] 2 4 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use "IRanges" package:

```
library(IRanges)

findOverlaps(IRanges(DF$V1, DF$V2), IRanges(DF$V1[1], DF$V2[1]))@queryHits
#[1] 1 2 4 6
```

Or generate all overlaps at once and subset later:

```
overls = findOverlaps(IRanges(DF$V1, DF$V2), ignoreSelf = TRUE)
split(subjectHits(overls), queryHits(overls))

subjectHits(overls)[queryHits(overls) == 1]
#[1] 2 4 6
```

"DF":

```
DF = structure(list(V1 = c(4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 3L), V2 = c(8L, 9L, 
2L, 7L, 14L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It's much better to use the accessor functions `subjectHits(overls)`, `queryHits(overls)` than direct slot access (also full TRUE and FALSE, since T can be assigned, `T = FALSE`, whereas TRUE cannot).